# Generate db with all combinations of 1X2

Tags: pandas, combinations

I want to create a db in Pandas with every combination of 1 or X or 2 for 8 games. Like this;

```
1 X 1        2 2
1 1 X        2 2
1 1 1        2 2
1 1 1        2 2
1 1 1        2 2
1 1 1        2 2
1 1 1        2 2
1 1 1 .....  X 2
```

and so on for all 6561 possible combinations.

I have tried using nested for loops but don't get i right. Any ideas?

Comment: You've lost me. Rows 3 to 7 are the exact same thing. What do you mean by 8 games? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Okey sorry, like this...

You read it vertical, one column = 8 series of games.

Every row = one soccer game
Every column = a serie of 8 different games
Every game (row) can be either 1, X or 2 

All in all there are 3^8 possible outcomes = 6561 columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which proposes functions to generate combinations. Here, use the cartesian product:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
pd.DataFrame(itertools.product([1,2,'X'], repeat=8))
```

Comment: Don´t seem to work? TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: I copy and pasted this code and it works for me just fine. @XavierBrt what version of pandas are you on? Consider upgrading to solve the error.

Comment: Yes it must be an error of version. I am using pandas 1.1.4 and python 3.8. `itertools` has been introduced since python 2.6.

Comment: Pandas is already updatet. Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.23.4)

Answer (score 0):

Ok update, it finally worked like this:

```
import itertools
x = [1, 'X', 2]
df = pd.DataFrame(p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=8))
print(df)
```

thanks for the help!